# TreeTagger on Cygwin

Tags: windows, cygwin, pos-tagger

I'd like to run TreeTagger with Cygwin but the installation fails with the following message:

> mkdir: cannot create directory `cmd': File exists
>   mkdir: cannot create directory`lib': File exists
>   mkdir: cannot create directory `bin': File exists
>   mkdir: cannot create directory`doc': File exists

awk: warning: command line argument `cmd/PaxHeaders.7369' is a directory: skipped
awk: warning: command line argument`cmd/PaxHeaders.7382' is a directory: skipped
Path variables modified in tagging scripts.

You might want to add /cygdrive/c/Corpus_Analysis/cygwin_tagger/cmd and /cygdrive/c/Corpus_Analysis/cygwin_tagger/bin to the PATH variable so that you do not need to specify the full path to run the tagging scripts.Blockquote

I've created a new path.
Thanks for help!

Comment: Are you not able to run the Windows interface; http://www.smo.uhi.ac.uk/~oduibhin/oideasra/interfaces/winttinterface.htm

Comment: Yes I am, but I wanted to run it from the command line as I do it in Linux - it's much faster. Thanks, anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the procedure described on http://www.smo.uhi.ac.uk/~oduibhin/oideasra/interfaces/winttinterface_old.htm and I can now run TreeTagger from my Cygwin window. Line numbers may have changed from the procedure described there, but with just a little common sense, it is easy to understand. I am writing an answer for this old thread so that if any others are struggling, they can know.
Just for information, I am running Cygwin on Windows 7, and I already had a Perl interpreter installed on my system.