# Installing TreeTagger on Windows with Cygewin to use with Python

Tags: cygwin, treetagger, cygwin-64

I want to use TreeTagger for PoS Tagging in German. I used it several years back and remember that the installation was not trivial back then. The installation has not become easier :-/

Now on a new machine I use [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Jc262cEF24) as guideline. I use Windows 10 professional, 64 Bit. Here are the installation steps I have done so far:

1. Download below five files from [the website](https://www.cis.uni-muenchen.de/%7Eschmid/tools/TreeTagger/) and put them in one directory.

- PC-Linux
- Tagging scripts
- German parameters
- German chunking
- Install-tagger.sh

2) Extract first four files with 7Zip to have *tar* or *par* files and put them in the same directory 


3) Create a folder TreeTagger and copy files from step 2 in this folder


4) Run Cygewin as an administrator


5) Change the directory to file locations, i.e. ```cd C:/TreeTagger```


6) Run *install-tagger.sh* file with ```sh install-tagger.sh```

--> It says that the tagging script, the German parameter and chunking files were installed. It also says that the path variables were modified in the tagging scripts.

Also, it says *You might want to add /cygdrive/c/TreeTagger/cmd and /cygdrive/c/TreeTagger/bin to the PATH variable so that you do not need to specify the full path to run the tagging scripts*


7) When I test the installation with `echo 'Das ist ein Test.' | cmd/tagger-chunker-german` I get the following error messages:

```
cmd/tagger-chunker-german: line 16: perl: command not found
cmd/tagger-chunker-german: line 17: /cygdrive/c/TreeTagger/bin/tree-tagger: No such file or directory
cmd/tagger-chunker-german: line 18: /cygdrive/c/TreeTagger/cmd/filter-chunker-output-german.perl: cannot execute: required file not found
/cygdrive/c/TreeTagger/cmd/tree-tagger-german: line 18: /cygdrive/c/TreeTagger/cmd/utf8-tokenize.perl: cannot execute: required file not found
cmd/tagger-chunker-german: line 19: /cygdrive/c/TreeTagger/bin/tree-tagger: No such file or directory
/cygdrive/c/TreeTagger/cmd/tree-tagger-german: line 20: perl: command not found
/cygdrive/c/TreeTagger/cmd/tree-tagger-german: line 22: /cygdrive/c/TreeTagger/bin/tree-tagger: No such file or directory
```

8. When I check the *bin* folder the required files are not there.
   So maybe I shouldn't use the *PC-Linux* installation file as suggested. I try again with the *ARM64* installation file and delete the files in the *TreeTagger* folder before I repeat steps 1 to 6.

--> Again it tells me that everything was installed properly. When I test it I get the following error messages

```
cmd/tagger-chunker-german: line 16: perl: command not found
cmd/tagger-chunker-german: line 17: /cygdrive/c/TreeTagger/bin/tree-tagger: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
cmd/tagger-chunker-german: line 18: /cygdrive/c/TreeTagger/cmd/filter-chunker-output-german.perl: cannot execute: required file not found
/cygdrive/c/TreeTagger/cmd/tree-tagger-german: line 18: /cygdrive/c/TreeTagger/cmd/utf8-tokenize.perl: cannot execute: required file not found
cmd/tagger-chunker-german: line 19: /cygdrive/c/TreeTagger/bin/tree-tagger: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
/cygdrive/c/TreeTagger/cmd/tree-tagger-german: line 20: perl: command not found
/cygdrive/c/TreeTagger/cmd/tree-tagger-german: line 22: /cygdrive/c/TreeTagger/bin/tree-tagger: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Maybe it did something funny during the extraction. So I repeat steps 2 to 6 but with only unzipping the *tree-tagger-ARM64* file. It runs through successfully. No error message in Cygwin. When I test the installation I get again error messages:

```
$ echo 'Das ist ein Test.' | cmd/tagger-chunker-german
cmd/tagger-chunker-german: line 16: perl: command not found
cmd/tagger-chunker-german: line 17: /cygdrive/c/TreeTagger/bin/tree-tagger: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
cmd/tagger-chunker-german: line 18: /cygdrive/c/TreeTagger/cmd/filter-chunker-output-german.perl: cannot execute: required file not found
/cygdrive/c/TreeTagger/cmd/tree-tagger-german: line 18: /cygdrive/c/TreeTagger/cmd/utf8-tokenize.perl: cannot execute: required file not found
cmd/tagger-chunker-german: line 19: /cygdrive/c/TreeTagger/bin/tree-tagger: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
/cygdrive/c/TreeTagger/cmd/tree-tagger-german: line 20: perl: command not found
/cygdrive/c/TreeTagger/cmd/tree-tagger-german: line 22: /cygdrive/c/TreeTagger/bin/tree-tagger: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

**Funny thing**, the file *filter-chunker-output-german* is present in the cmd folder. When I try the command `echo 'Das ist ein Test.' | cmd/tree-tagger-german` it says that the files *utf8-tokenize.perl* is not there but I can see it.

Last but not least, it did not let me add PATH variables */cygdrive/c/TreeTagger/cmd* or */cygdrive/c/TreeTagger/bin*. Adding the PATH variable *C:/TreeTagger/cmd* and *C:/TreeTagger/bin* hasn't resolved the issue.

**So the big question is, how to install TreeTagger?** 
Any help is appreciated.  In the end I like to use TreeTagger with the [Python Wrapper](https://treetaggerwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Looking at previous posts I couldn't figure out a solution. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15503388/treetagger-installation-successful-but-cannot-open-par-file) was useful but installs the files directly from the server. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23646730/treetagger-on-cygwin) wants to use TreeTaggers standalone GUI. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43318458/using-treetagger-with-python-cant-find-the-treetagger-bin) wants to install it directly from Python but I read somewhere that this is not ideal for security reasons. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19957656/running-treetagger) has a permission error with TreeTagger.